# Style own app like the default Facebook design

Tags: css, facebook

I want to style the buttons on my own Facebook app like the normal Facebook UI,
e.g. tabs should look like that:

[image]

The apps is embed to an iframe so I (think I) can't use the CSS classes from FB?!

Comment: Show what you have done so far?

Comment: See the heading ;)... Dennis M understood what I meant ;)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/tab-item/
It's called fb:tabs - Renders a group of standard Facebook navigation tabs. Must contain at least one fb:tab-item.
It's the part of FBML - Facebook Markup Language which they are deprecating and neither fb recommends you to use nor i recommend, its better to do it using css, but you can use it for as long as it works :)

Here you go, CSS for facebook style tabs:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Facebook Style Tabs</title>
<style>
body {
    background:#fff;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande",Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:left;
}
a {
    color:#3b5998;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display:block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
/**********************************************************NAVIGATION TABS************************************************************/
.fb-tabs {
    border-bottom:1px solid #898989;
    padding:3px 0px;
    /* top and bottom,left and right */
}
.fb-tabs .left_tabs {
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.fb-tabs .right_tabs {
    float:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.fb-tabitems {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}
.fb-tabitems li {
    display:inline;
    padding:2px 0px 3px;
    /*top,left and right,bottom*/
    background:#f1f1f1 url(http://www.facebook.com/images/components/toggle_tab_gloss.gif) top left repeat-x;
}
.fb-tabitems li a {
    border:1px solid #898989;
    color:#333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 8px 3px 9px;
}
.fb-tabitems li a small {
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.fb-tabitems li a:focus {
    outline:0px;
}
.fb-tabitems li.first a /*only for the first anchor of the list*/ {
    border:1px solid #898989;
}
.fb-tabitems li a.selected {
    background:#6d84b4;
    border:1px solid #3b5998;
    border-left:1px solid #5973a9;
    border-right:1px solid #5973a9;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:-1px;
}
.fb-tabitems li.last a.selected {
    margin-left:-1px;
    border-left:1px solid #5973a9;
    border-right:1px solid #36538f;
}
.fb-tabitems li.first.last a.selected {
    border:1px solid #36538f;
}
.fb-tabitems li a.selected:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fb-tabs clearfix">
    <center>
        <div class="left_tabs">
            <ul class="fb-tabitems clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">NavbarLink1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="selected">NavbarLink2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NavbarLink3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right_tabs">
            <ul class="fb-tabitems clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">NavbarLink1Right</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NavbarLink2Right</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=86504

Comment: Thanks, yes that's normally what I looked for but as you mentioned they are deprecating it...so is there another solution? Or do I really have to copy the CSS styles from Facebook?

Comment: No problem, well yes you have to copy the CSS and that's the only solution i have for now. Other than that i don't know any other solutions.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the CSS code and html for facebook style tabs, got it from their forum, check out here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=86504

You can get other styles as well, like button style,dashboard.etc.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can...look into the source code from facebook for the source of their stylesheets. Or use [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) in Firefox or Opera Dragonfly or any other web development plugin to get the CSS properties.

BUT don't recreate Facebook, I don't think that they would appreciate it!